# How to set font size/weight for small ticks in simple Matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I try to make a simple plot and set the size and weight of the font for ticks, however, even after reading `matplotlib` manual I am not clear what is the algorithm for that.

I am using recommended OOP-approach with `matplotlib 3.3`.
Here is the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
print(x)
y = x**2
z = 1 + 5*x

# Plotting:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color='blue', linewidth=2.0, label="Quadratic")
ax.plot(x, z, color='orange', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1.5, label="Linear")
# Axis limits
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

# Axis labels
ax.set_xlabel(r"A linear array of $X$ values", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel(r"Some functions $y(x)$", fontsize=16)

# Ticks:
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())

ax.set_title("Some simple plots", loc='left')
ax.legend(frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

**Questions:**

- How to specify font size (in pt) and font weight (i.e. bold) for labels on both major and minor ticks? I found a way to specify font size via `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)`, but I cannot find a way to turn font bold.
- Can I specify font parameters for tick labels only via `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params()`? Is there a way to specify font parameters via Formatters?
- I have installed monospaced font "Source Code Pro". How can I use this specific font for my Matplotlib? Can I specify the path to the font?

I know that my questions might be basic, but I cannot clarify an algorithm for formatting of tick labels. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to specify font size (in pt) and font weight (i.e. bold) for labels on both major and minor ticks?

If you just want to set the label size, then `tick_params` is more easier to use. To set the font weight, then you can get the `Text` instance for each tick labels by `Axis.get_majorticklabels`:

```py
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_fontweight('bold')

# similar for minor tick labels by get_minorticklabels
```

> Can I specify font parameters for tick labels only via ax.xaxis.set_tick_params()? Is there a way to specify font parameters via Formatters?

As I said above, `tick_params` is a better choice if the fontweight is not involved. As far as I know, `Formatter` is not related to font properties, but to the numeric representation of tick labels. So I don't think font properties can be specified via `Formatter`.

> I have installed monospaced font "Source Code Pro". How can I use this specific font for my Matplotlib? Can I specify the path to the font?

The question can be transformed to `how to specify the font name in matplotlib`. You can find the font name in the property when you right click the font file. Alternatively, you can use the `set_fontproperties` method of `Text` instance to set the font by the file path, such as:

```py
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_fontweight('bold')
    tick.set_fontproperties(pathlib.WindowsPath(r'C:\Users\Downloads\TTF-source-code-pro-2.038R-ro-1.058R-it\SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf'))
```